# How to link Cognito Identity ID with User Attributes?

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a user login system for an iOS application written Swift 3. With the code below I get the unique Cognito Identity ID for the user in my User Pool but I am not sure what to do with this ID. Can I link it to the user and get the attributes associated with that user?

Code:

```
@IBAction func loginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    user = self.pool!.getUser(usernameTextField.text!)
    user?.getSession(usernameTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, validationData: nil).continue({ task in
        if let err = task.error {  // some sort of error
            print("LOGIN FAILED")
            print(err)
            //print(err.userInfo["message"] as! String)
        }
        else { //Successful login!

            // this gets our token from the User Pool
            let ret = task.result! as AWSCognitoIdentityUserSession
            let myToken = ret.idToken?.tokenString;

            print("Token: ", myToken);

            let customcedentialProvider = AWSCustomIdentityProvider(tokens: [AWSCustomIdentityProvider.CognitoTokenKey : myToken!])
            let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: CognitoConstants.COGNITO_REGIONTYPE, identityPoolId: CognitoConstants.COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,  identityProviderManager: customcedentialProvider)
            let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: CognitoConstants.COGNITO_REGIONTYPE, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)
            AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

            // wipe cached creds
            credentialsProvider.clearKeychain()
            credentialsProvider.clearCredentials()

            // hit it
            credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continue({ (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in

                if (task.error != nil) {
                    print("Error: ")

                } else {

                    // the task result will contain the identity id
                    let UserIdentityID = task.result as String? // Im saving user identity id in constant variable called "kUserIdentityID"
                    print(UserIdentityID)// my identityID
                    print(credentialsProvider.identityId)// my identityID
                }

                return nil
            })

        }
    return nil
    })
}
```

Output (Identity ID):

```
Optional("us-east-1:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with the swift code. Played around with this using javascript. So, Cognito UserPool is an "identity provider" like Facebook, Google etc. Whereas Cognito Federated Identity helps to keep the mappings between different logins to one unique id, which is often called "Cognito Identity ID". Typically you store and retrieve data inside datasets under Cognito Federated identity. And sync those for multiple logins. If I understand your question, you may want to store the userpool "username" in the above mentioned dataset so that you can retrieve it and query the userpool.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I did not have a solid understanding of the tool. I was able to create the dataset on the user sign up with user information. When logging in I am now able to get the user information and proceed to the application as an authenticated user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito UserPool is an "identity provider" like Facebook, Google etc. Whereas Cognito Federated Identity helps to keep the mappings between different logins to one unique id, which is often called "Cognito Identity ID". Typically you store and retrieve data inside datasets under Cognito Federated identity. And sync those for multiple logins. If I understand your question, you may want to store the userpool "username" in the above mentioned dataset so that you can retrieve it and query the userpool

Answer (score 1):

The self.pool refers to your Cognito User Pool.  User pools have at least a username and password, but usually also other attributes, which you can fetch using user.getDetails.  A user pool is an IdP (an Identity Provider).

The identityId is a Cognito Identity concept which primarily has the purpose of providing a unique id for one or more identities from IdP's.

Don't worry about being confused. Cognito is very confusing, I found it so confusing that I wrote up a little powerpoint presentation from my notes. Here is a link to a diagram that should help you.[Diagram of Cognito](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/SignIn-awsmhh/blob/master/cognito%20diagram.pdf)

Also, I would like to suggest that you use the AWS Mobile Hub Helper as a starting point.  It will download a swift code sample app.  And the sample code uses the aws-mobilehub-helper-ios wrapper which simplifies a lot of the SDK and makes it more rational.  The downloaded code is Swift2 but it is not too hard to get running in swift 3.